# How to print in this string

Tags: c

I have a string like this.

```
char array1[250] = {"Array Values are %d,%d,%d,%d"};
```

And I have four integers like this,

```
int var1 = 25,var2 = 78, var3 = -189,var4 = -200;
```

I would like to print var1 to var4 in array1. How do I do that? I already have the format specifiers in array1 itself.

Comment: `strlen("Array Values are 25,78,-189,-200") == 32`; thus your array would need to be 33 bytes or larger for this to even be valid.

Comment: In response to some of the answers to this question: From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sprintf.html: "If copying takes place between objects that overlap as a result of a call to sprintf() or snprintf(), the results are undefined."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sprintf(array1, array1, var1, var2, var3, var4);`

Does it.  However I'm not sure how kindly C will react to reading and writing to the same string at the same time, strongly advise you copy it into a separate variable first.

Edit:  Per Roddy's comment I'm just going to say *don't* do what you are asking to do at all.  Format specifier should be separated from data, I'm positive the application you're using this in can spare 25 bytes for good design.

Comment: I'm 99% sure it *can't* work, because sprintf doesn't make a temp copy of the format string. It would also write  way past the end of the array, given the example values, and - just to cap it off - the literal string would likely be stored in a read-only section of memory.

Comment: @Roddy: It's assigned to a char array, so the literal isn't a problem. Everything else you mentioned will be.

Comment: You have overlap => undefined behavior.

Comment: @nneoneo - You're right. I was thinking char* rather than char[]

Comment: @Roddy there is no string literal here.

Comment: @ouah - there is, but it's copied to the char array as nneoneo notes.

Comment: @Roddy yes, my comment is ill-written, there is indeed a string literal. I wanted to point that `char array1[] = {"Array Values are %d,%d,%d,%d"};` is equivalent to `char array1[] = "Array Values are %d,%d,%d,%d";`

Comment: If you can find *any* compiler that this works on, I'll give you an upvote. Until then, downvoted :-(  ideone.org, for example, fails badly. http://ideone.com/fUNaG

Answer (score 2):

Don't put the format specifier in the array. Just do

```
char array1[128]; // enough space for four ints and the string

sprintf(array1, "Array Values are %d,%d,%d,%d", var1, var2, var3, var4);
```

Comment: Good suggestion sir, but I would like the way I stated.

Comment: You are trying to write into your format string, which, as Alok already pointed out is UB. This is really the easiest way to do it. If you want the format string in a variable, define a separate variable for the format string.

Comment: @user1293997 in that case use a temporary array.

Answer (score 0):

simply use [sprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf)

but create another output array, or you would have undefined behavior because you overwrite the format string.

```
char output[126];

sprintf(output, array1, var1, var2, var3, var4);
```

Comment: You have overlap => undefined behavior.